# The JVM level keep changed to the version that I don't want when building spring project

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I am currently in the need to create a Spring project with Java version 8. I have set Java to the version 8 and the JDK is 1.8. However, when I build it - I got this notification
[image]

Which indeed turn my Java into 17 in my pom.xml . I tried to change the version from my pom and synced it but when I rebuild my project again I got this error
[image]

Upgrading my java version to above 8 is not an option. How to fix this?

//edit:
pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: bytecode version 61.0 is for class files compiled with jdk17 compiler, so maybe you could clean and rebuild whole project to resolve that.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?  Spring 6.x.x **requires** Java 17.

Comment: @MNEMO I have tried clean the lifecycle of the maven then rebuild it. but the problem remains

Comment: @StephenC I have edit my question with my pom file and my Spring should 3.0.0

Comment: Ah yes.  I see you originally said Spring but you are actually using SpringBoot ... which is versioned differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot 3.0.0 requires Java 17 and upwards to be compatible with the new features. If you really want to use Java 1.8 I would suggest downgrading the Spring Boot version to the previous stable version which is `2.7.6`

Comment: Thank you that fixed the problem! I end up changing it to `2.7.5` tho but this lead me to an understanding of where I did wrong